# Re-pointing one module to another module in __init__.py

Tags: python, import, module

I'm trying to point an old module implementation to a new one with the code below but I'm getting AttributeError/ImportError when the module itself is imported. Any idea how to fix this? And why is oldpack.sub.mymodule not visible even though it's in sys.modules?

```
/oldpack/sub/__init__.py
    import sys
    import newpack.sub.mymodule
    sys.modules['oldpack.sub.mymodule'] = sys.modules['newpack.sub.mymodule']


/somepack/app.py
    from oldpack.sub.mymodule import some_func, SomeClass # works fine: we got some_func and SomeClass from newpack.sub.mymodule
    import oldpack.sub.mymodule # raises AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'mymodule'
    from oldpack.sub import mymodule # raises ImportError: cannot import name mymodule
```

PS I want to avoid modifying oldpack.sub.mymodule so updating it to 
from newpack.sub.mymodule import * is not ideal.

**SOLVED**
I've fixed the errors. When a module is loaded two things happen, the module gets added to sys.modules and the module is added as an attribute to the parent package (see add_submodule in import.c). So to take care of the latter, I updated line#2 in  `/oldpack/sub/__init__.py`

```
    import sys
    from newpack.sub import mymodule # by importing this way, we simulate the adding of the module as attribute to the parent package
    sys.modules['oldpack.sub.mymodule'] = mymodule
```

The 2nd and 3rd import in `/somepack/app.py` didn't work earlier because they rely on the module being available as attribute in the package. For details, take a look at the bytecodes of those two import statements using dis.dis().